# Simple conditional for handling the Tags (JQuery , javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I want to write a conditional to handle tags.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + Math.random() * 100);
    $('#div2').html(number);
    var $div3 = $("#div3");
    if (number > 50) {
      var span1 = $('<span />').addClass('yes').text('YES');
      span1.appendTo($div3);
      checkSpan(span1);
    } else {
      var span2 = $('<span />').addClass('no').text(' NO');
      span2.appendTo($div3);
    }
  }, 1000);
});

function checkSpan($span) {
  if ($span.prevUntil('.no', '.yes').length === 2) {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.yes'), function(e) {
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    });
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.no'), function(e) {
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    });
    var Reset = $('<span />').addClass('reset').text("RESET");
    Reset.appendTo($("#div3"));
  }
}
```

```css
.yes,
.no,
.reset {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}

.yes {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
}

.reset {
  background-color: #5f79ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #cce1ee;text-align: center;width: 500px;height: 500px;margin: 0 auto;">
  <input id="btn" value="click" type="button" style="' + 'text-align: center;width: 50px" />
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

here we see after (3 `<span class="yes">YES</span>`) all spans tag with class `.yes` and `.no` will be remove
and the this `<span class="reset">RESET</span>` is created .

now i want a conditional => if after `<span class="reset">RESET</span>` is there `<span class="yes">YES</span>` ?
if yes?
so alert ("there is span tag with class yes after Reset")
else {
alert ("there is no span tag with class yes after Reset")
}

Example :

if

```
<span class="reset">Reset</span>
<span class="yes">YES</span>
```

do stuff ....

Comment: Does this help? [if..else..](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: its not clear ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that `checkSpan()` function can possibly work.

Comment: no because it must check (.reset) and after that is there (.yes) ?

Comment: @Pointy why?
it works

Comment: @Alex yea I get it now. Still, `$(".yes").each()` would be simpler probably; you're already using jQuery.

Comment: could you write it please ?
that where is the problem ?

Comment: No no, I just found that code a little confusing, while (in a jQuery context) there's a simpler-looking way to do it.

Comment: ok if you have simpler method , i will be happy to learn it :)

Comment: no answer ? :( is my question really hard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you want:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var nbyes = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + Math.random() * 100);
    $('#div2').html(number);
    var $div3 = $("#div3");
    if (number > 50) {
      if(nbyes == 3){
         nbyes = 0;
         alert("there is span tag with class yes after Reset");
      }
      var span1 = $('<span />').addClass('yes').text('YES');
      span1.appendTo($div3);
      nbyes++;
      if(nbyes == 3){
         checkSpan();
      }
    } else {
      if(nbyes == 3){
         nbyes = 0;
         alert("there is no span tag with class yes after Reset");
      }    
      var span2 = $('<span />').addClass('no').text(' NO');
      span2.appendTo($div3);
    }
  }, 1000);
});

function checkSpan($span) {
  $(".yes, .no").remove(); 
  var Reset = $('<span />').addClass('reset').text("RESET");
  Reset.appendTo($("#div3"));
}
```

```css
.yes,
.no,
.reset {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}

.yes {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
}

.reset {
  background-color: #5f79ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #cce1ee;text-align: center;width: 500px;height: 500px;margin: 0 auto;">
  <input id="btn" value="click" type="button" style="' + 'text-align: center;width: 50px" />
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why? can you explain

Comment: i am not sure if the process is blocked..i think you have to abort the settime out and relaunch after

Comment: this is true , and how can set if after class (.reset) 
if 2 or more (.yes) classes are created . do something ...

Comment: so you abort the settimeout and relaunch if needed

Comment: how can abort settimeout and restart it?

Comment: its no complex but you have to change the logic of your program.and its not the same problem.so i suggest you to ask a new question